# Get the sum total of a value from flatlist react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to get the sum total of all the value retrieve from my fetch in a FlatList below is my code.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={numList}
        listKey="number-list"
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.ticSec}>
                    <Text>{item.amount}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }}
    />
</SafeAreaView>
```

The Output result:

```
10
20
15
```

How can I make it output sum total of of `45` whick is the sometotal of `10,20,15`

thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `Array.prototype.reduce` to calculate the sum of the amounts of all items in your `numList` like so:

```js
const sumTotal = numList.reduce((acc, next) => {
  return acc + next.amount
}, 0)
```

where `acc` stands for `accumulator` and `next` is the next item we iterate over.

you can then use the value in your jsx:

```js
<Text>{sumTotal}</Text>
```

More about `reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thanks for your respond the output am getting is `0102015` not `45`

Comment: I see. It seems that the value stored in the `amount` property is a `string` and not, as expected, a `number`. when you try to add a string to a number, Javascript will convert the number to a string, and concacenate (join) them. In your case, it's `0 + "10" + "20" + "15"`, which equals "0102015".

I would recommend fixing it so that `item.amount` is a number, not a string.

Comment: If fixing `item.amount` is not possible, then use the following operation inside the reduce block: `return acc + parseInt(next.amount, 10)`

Comment: After apply this `return acc + parseInt(next.amount, 10)` it worked